# iOS 13 Shortcuts URL "Cannot connect to server"

Tags: ios, nfc, sirishortcuts

I am trying to make an automation shortcut on my iPhone, when reading a NFC tag it should execute an URL. When I create the shortcut and press the 'Run' button to test it, it executes normally. 
However, when I exit the app, and read the NCF tag then Shortcuts gives me an error "Cannot connect to Server". I tried using an ip number for the server, local domain name (.local), but none of it works.

Anyone an idea why it works fine if you test, but not when you actually trigger the shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be caused by in-secure http access.. for some reason a http call works when you try the shortcut, but when you trigger it, it fails. Using https solved the issue.